# 70s Book about a girl who gets replaced with an android

Tags: story-identification, books, androids

Read this book in the 70s.

Looking for a book about a young girl who gets replaced with an android. It replaces her in her real life and she gets to eat all the candy and chocolate that she wants. After a while she gets sick of eating it all and starts losing weight and they have to make the android smaller.

Comment: Can we get you to go to https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info and see if answering those questions (and editing them into your question) will elicit more details?

Comment: ^_^ And, pedant that I am, would that be a gynoid?

Comment: Similar to [_The Duplicate_](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/24884.The_Duplicate) but not quite the same.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't [The Adventures of the Elektronic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Adventures_of_the_Elektronic) (1979) ? It has a boy instead of a girl, but otherwise sounds like it as a similar plot. Even how later the android looks different after a year. Also potentially [My Robot Buddy](https://www.amazon.com/My-Robot-Buddy-Alfred-Slote/dp/0064401650), also a boy with a LMD look-a-like that he uses to replace him, written in the 1970s.